# Stored procedures and inserts for PDO

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, pdo

Hey guys im currently running stored procedurs for select queries but have run into trouble for INSERT'S the syntax for the php part is

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('makereview(:title, :user, :rating, :description)');
    $stmt->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);                   
    $stmt->bindValue(':rating', $rating, PDO::PARAM_INT);   
    $stmt->bindValue(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_INT);         
    $stmt->execute();
```

The error it throws is syntax error on the prepare line not sure why, the procedure is correct but it doesnt seem to like attempting the call.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldnt that SQL statement be preceded by CALL?

```
 CALL makereview() etc
```